# How to add the value of an id of one table into another on select?

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables Table 1 and Table 2 .

What I expect is the below format.
*Required format*

```
Table 1    
   ID   Title   S_ID    
   1    Option1   2    
   2    Option2   2    
   3    Option3   1  

Table 2       
   S_ID  SNAME    
   1     Name1    
   2     Name2    
   3     Name3
```

But I am getting a `null` value for `S_ID` of Table1.

```
Table 1    
   ID   Title   S_ID    
   1    Option1   NULL    
   2    Option2   NULL    
   3    Option3   NULL

Table 2    
   S_ID  SNAME    
   1     Name1    
   2     Name2    
   3     Name3
```

Here is my code:

HTML :

```
<select name=sid>
<option value="select"></option>
<option value="N1">Name1</option>
<option value="N2">Name2</option>
<option value="N3">Name3</option>
</select>
```

Insert.php

```
$title=$_POST['title'];
$sid=$_POST['S_ID'];    
$insertquery="INSERT INTO review (title) VALUES('$title')";
```

What I need is when I select any name from drop down, the `id` of that from Table 2 should get stored in Table 1 as shown in the above required format, and retrieve the titles that comes under respective names on click of particular name.

Do help by writing required code. Thank You.

Comment: I would definitely consider sanitizing the input for your query or you are vulnerable for a SQL injection.

Comment: I am a-bit confused. Please provide a proper description. Also please provide some more of your code thatyou have tried

Comment: **Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attack.**  You *really* should be using [prepared statements](http://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/623041), into which you pass your variables as parameters that do not get evaluated for SQL.  If you don't know what I'm talking about, or how to fix it, read the story of [Bobby Tables](http://stackoverflow.com/q/332365/623041).

Comment: First you check the value is coming in insert.php page, so use
print_r($_POST);
then try it,or knew me what happen

Comment: It's taking the value from the form . I've stored the values in Table 2 . When i select a name from Table 2 , it's id should get stored in Table 1's S_ID column .

Comment: @Roger When i select a name from drop down on my home page , it's taking the value from the form . I've stored the values in Table 2 . When i select a name from Table 2 , it's id should get stored in Table 1's [ S_ID ] column .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO your `INSERT` statement should look like this:

```
$insertquery = "INSERT INTO review (title, S_ID) VALUES('$title', '$sid')";
```

And you definitely need to consider sanitizing input and using prepared statements.

**Update:**

You can populate your `select` with options from Table 2 (and assuming that you use `mysqli`) you can do something like this:

```php
<?php

$db = new mysqli("host", "user", "password", "db");

$qry = "SELECT * FROM Table2";
$result = $db->query($qry);
echo "<select name=\"S_ID\">";
echo "<option value=\"select\" selected=\"selected\">Select a name</option>";
while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<option value=\"" . $row['S_ID'] . "\">" . $row['SNAME'] . "</option>";
}
echo '</select>';
$result->close();
$db->close();

?>
```

For sake of brevity and simplicity there are no checks.

Comment: I'll sanitize it for sure . Does your insertquery take values from table or from form ?

Comment: According to your `insert.php` it comes from the form with `$_POST['S_ID']`. I hope you populate values for options in your `<select name="sid">` from the Table 2

Comment: What if i want to take it from Table 2 ?

Comment: Could u tell me how to populate values from Table 2 to my from ?

Comment: Thanks alot Sir.. And i also had asked about how to retrieve the contents of Table 1 on selection of any name ?

Comment: Almost the same way. Your `SELECT` statement will look like this  `$qry = "SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE S_ID='$sid'";` Then  render your html while iterating through the resultset.